# python shelve sync gdbm fatal: read error

Tags: python, shelve

I'm using a shelve-object which I opened with `writeback=True`.
Whenever there are changes to the shelve-object, I am calling the sync-method.
After 20 minutes I always get this error (without any traceback information):

> gdbm fatal: read error

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS as VM with Windows 10 Professional and Hyper V as host.

Comment: It would help if you included your code but this kind of error might occur when you are running out of space in your partition.

Answer (score 0):

`gdbm` is the underlying linux implementation the `shelve` relies upon. Something must go wrong there. It might require some investigation to know what went wrong there.

Here is an alternative if you want https://github.com/dagnelies/pysos